# SQL ORACLE: How to replace a character by its HEX value

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to replace a character based on its HEX value (x96) in SELECT statement.
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: One single character, or a character inside a string?

Comment: character inside a string

Comment: Did you search anything

Comment: I tried: select replace('Job  test – - tes', 'x96', '') from dual.But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal `96` is decimal `150` the corresponding character is `chr(150)`

To remove this character from a string use the following replace (I simulate the character is the string with concatenation).

```
select replace ('test'||chr(150)||'text',chr(to_number( '96', 'xx' )), '') from dual;

 testtext
```

Answer (score 1):

ASCII function returns the NUMBER code that represents the specified character.

xxxxxx - conver decimal to hex.

fm - remove trailing spaces

```
select replace('Test text to replace','e',to_char (ascii('e'), 'fmxxxxxx')) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(text_field, unistr('\0096'), 'x') from table_name;
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)